# Thesis with multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, thesis

i am working with my thesis in overleaf and am using a template because I am at the beginning of my Latex journey. This template works with a thesisstyle.sty file with contains the information on the bibliography like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{thesisstyle} 
    
%%%%%%% Bibliography 
    
 \RequirePackage{mathscinet} 
 \RequirePackage[backend    = bibtex,
                            sortcites  = true,
                            giveninits = true,
                            sortlocale = nb_NO,
                            style      = vancouver,
                            refsection = chapter]{biblatex} 
    \addbibresource{bibliographies/chapter1.bib} 
    \addbibresource{bibliographies/chapter2.bib} 
    \addbibresource{bibliographies/chapter3.bib}     
    \addbibresource{bibliographies/chapter4.bib}
```

In the main document i combine multiple .tex files like this:

```
\usepackage{thesisstyle}   % Thesisstyle
\includeonly
{
    sections/introduction,
    sections/thesisaims,
    sections/materials,
    sections/discussion,
}

\begin{document}
    \include{sections/introduction}
    \include{sections/thesisaims}
    \include{sections/materials}
    \include{sections/discussion}
\end{document}
```

As you can see every section has its own `chapter1.bib` file etc.

I want to print a bibliography after the discussions section which includes all the references from all the previous sections (introduction,thesisaims,materials,discussion). If i use `\printbibliography` after `\include{sections/discussion}` command it will only print me the bibliography of the discussion but not from the previous sections.

How could I manage to get the complete bibliography after the discussions part?

Help is much appreciated. I deleted much of the `thesisstyle.sty` and also `main.tex` file in this post in order to give a better overview in this post. But please tell me if you need more information provided.

Kind regards!

Comment: you are using `refsection = chapter`. That means that every chapter has its own bibliography. If you want to combine the bibliographies of more than one chapter you must remove this setting and use \refsection manually when you want to start a new unit, see the biblatex documentation for more info.

Comment: I removed the refsection and now I have the bibliography - many thanks. I just get the warning:                            l.91 
     
The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.
Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as the first line of the file
or specify an encoding such as \usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
in the document preamble.
Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool.                                                              Using \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenx}